# react ui displays previous state even when the state updates

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and still learning. I`m working on a simple todo app with two routes: / and` /:id`

The problem is every time I go back to all tasks and choose one - when it redirects me to `/:id`, it is supposed to fetch the task with of the given id. And it does, but shows the previously chosen task. When I consolelog current state, I see that on the first render it has the old currentNote task, and then it updates to the correct one, but UI is already showing the old data, even tho it already has a new one.

I wanted to have currentNote accessible globally, so I wrapped it in a callback function.

NotesContext.jsx

```
const getNote = useCallback(async function getNote(id) {
    try {
      setIsLoading(true);
      const response = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/api/v1/tasks/${id}`);
      const data = await response.json();
      setCurrentNote(data.task);
    } catch (error) {
      alert("There was an error fetching the note");
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }, []);
```

NotePage.jsx

```
const { id } = useParams();
const [isCompleted, setIsCompleted] = useState(false);
const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
const { currentNote } = useContext(NotesContext);

  useEffect(
    function () {
      getNote(id);
    },
    [id, getNote]
  );

  useEffect(
    function () {
      setIsCompleted(currentNote.completed);
      setDescription(currentNote.description);
    },
    [currentNote]
  );
 
return <.. UI ..>
```

Comment: This issue happens when you don't umount the component properly. It will be easy to tell the issue if you provide the complete code for NotePage.jsx including UI code